# Searching for files but may need to time out

Tags: batch-file

I have a program to search drives for a specific file. The only problem is is that i wont know what drive it is on. The problem occurs when it searches a drive for a file that isn't there is there a way to go on to the next drive after say like 10 seconds. Heres my code so far

```
    @echo off


setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

 set count=1
 for /f "skip=1" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') do (
  set drive!count!=%%a
  set /a count+=1
)

set "gh=!drive1!"
::Change this to do whatever with the variables
set "fh=!drive2!"
set "hh=!drive3!"
set "jh=!drive4!"

For /R %gh%\ %%G IN (*.ut2) do set jk="%%~dpG"
if defined jk (
echo %jk%
) else (
goto next
)

for /r %jk% %%a in (*) do if "%%~nxa"=="CTF-Hydro-16-2k3.ut2" set  k=%%~dpnxa
if defined k (
echo %k% found
pause
cls
echo You have it
goto end
) else (
echo Map not found
copy %CD:~0,3%\Unrealmap\CTF-Hydro-16-2k3.ut2 %jk%
goto end
)

:next

For /R %fh%\ %%G IN (*.ut2) do set ht="%%~dpG"
if defined ht (
echo %ht%
) else (
goto there
)

for /r %ht% %%a in (*) do if "%%~nxa"=="CTF-Hydro-16-2k3.ut2" set m=%%~dpnxa
if defined k (
echo %m% found
pause
cls
echo You have it
goto end
) else (
echo Map not found
copy %CD:~0,3%\Unrealmap\CTF-Hydro-16-2k3.ut2 %jk%
goto end

:there
:end
cls
echo done
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1" %%D in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') do (
    for /r "%%D\\" %%G IN (*.ut2) do (
        echo %%~dpG
        if exist "%%~dpGCTF-Hydro-16-2k3.ut2" (
            echo Found the map.
            goto end
        ) else (
            echo Map not found, copying
            copy %CD:~0,3%\Unrealmap\CTF-Hydro-16-2k3.ut2 "%%~dpG"
            goto end
        )
    )
)
:end
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Try next approach:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions
set /A "ii=0"
for /f "skip=1" %%D in ('
    wmic logicaldisk get caption
    ') do for /F %%d in ("%%D") do (
  echo searching %%d
  for /F "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /B /S "%%d\CTF-Hydro-16-2k3.ut2" 2^>nul') do (
    set /A "ii+=1"
    set "k=%%G"
    rem remove 'rem' from next line to discontinue searching 
    rem goto :testfound
  )
  TIMEOUT /T 10 /NOBREAK >NUL
)
:testfound
if %ii% EQU 0 (
  echo Map not found
) else (
  echo Map found %ii% times: last one "%k%"
)
```

Here the `for` loops against `wmic` command are

- `%%D` to retrieve the `caption` value;
- `%%d` to remove the ending *carriage return* in the value returned: `wmic` behaviour: each output line ends with `0x0D0D0A` (`<CR><CR><LF>`) instead of common `0x0D0A` (`<CR><LF>`).

See Dave Benham's [*`WMIC` and `FOR /F`: A fix for the trailing `<CR>` problem*](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266)

Another eventuality: parse

```
wmic datafile where "Extension='ut2' and FileName='CTF-Hydro-16-2k3'" get Name 2>NUL
```